# How to force cache files in workbox or sw?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

How force workbox to cache again the files? even they not has changed?

for the first time all the files are cached:

```
registerServiceWorker.ts:14 Service worker has been registered.
registerServiceWorker.ts:24 New content is downloading.
logger.mjs:44 workbox Precaching 9 files.
registerServiceWorker.ts:21 Content has been cached for offline use.
```

When I have a new version of service worker its say (but I change the files after the build for example I add content to `index.html` file by `fs.writeFileSync`):

```
registerServiceWorker.ts:24 New content is downloading.
logger.mjs:44 workbox Precaching 0 files. 9 files are already cached.
registerServiceWorker.ts:27 New content is available; please refresh.
```

Which is bad, because `index.html` changed but the build is the same. so I looking a way to force cache the files again.

One way is delete all the files in the cache. but trust me its complicated for my app right now. so I looking for a way to force update/override the cache.